# How to maintain a session with .aspx server while web scraping through pagination?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, web-scraping, request-promise

I am unable to maintain a session with a .aspx server. I am trying to scrape data by paginating, but it keeps telling me "The Results have expired. Please resubmit the search." I have tried maintaining cookies so I don't think that is the problem unless I somehow did it wrong?

I have to navigate through by first making a GET request to the following URL:

https://www.wandsworth.gov.uk/planning-and-building-control/search-planning-applications/

The following is the code I use to make the request.

First these are all my requires

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const url = require('url');
const rp = require('request-promise');
const ss = require('string-similarity');
const tc = require('tough-cookie');
```

Here is how I make my request

```
var options = {
  uri: 'https://www.wandsworth.gov.uk/planning-and-building-control/search-planning-applications/',
  transform: function(body){ return cheerio.load(body) },
  method: 'GET'
}

var $ = await rp(options);
```

Now I extract the information I need in order to make a successful post request, and I use the 'string-similarity' package to find a select element that closely matches a  tag that matches my input.

```
// Extract selectable elements
var obj_collection = $('#cboStreetReferenceNumber')[0].children;
var collection = []; // array of inner strings for each select element

// Push innerHTML strings to collection
for(let i=0; i<obj_collection.length; i++){
     try {
         collection.push(obj_collection[i].children[0].data);
     } catch(e) {
         collection.push('');
     }
}

// Find the best match for our given address
var matches = ss.findBestMatch(address, collection);
var cboStreetReferenceNumber=
obj_collection[matches.bestMatchIndex].attribs.value;

// These are used to verify us
var __VIEWSTATE = $('#__VIEWSTATE')[0].attribs.value;
var __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = $('#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')[0].attribs.value;
var __EVENTVALIDATION = $('#__EVENTVALIDATION')[0].attribs.value;
var cboMonths = 1;
var cboDays = 1;
var csbtnSearch = 'Select';
var rbGroup = 'rbNotApplicable';

// Modify options
options.uri = $('#M3Form')[0].attribs.action;
options.method = 'POST';
options.form = { 
cboStreetReferenceNumber,
__VIEWSTATE,
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
__EVENTVALIDATION,
cboMonths,
cboDays,
csbtnSearch,
rbGroup
};      
options.followAllRedirects = true;
options.resolveWithFullResponse = true;
delete options.transform;
```

Now with these options, I'm ready to make my request to page 1 of the data I'm looking for.

```
// method: @POST
// link: "Planning Explorer"
var body = await rp(options);
var $ = cheerio.load(body.body);
console.log(body.request);
var Referer = 'https://planning1.wandsworth.gov.uk' + body.req.path;

var scroll_uri = 'https://planning1.wandsworth.gov.uk/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/Generic/StdResults.aspx?PT=Planning%20Applications%20On-Line&PS=10&XMLLoc=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/generic/XMLtemp/ekgjugae3ox3emjpzvjtq045/c6b04e65-fb83-474f-b6bb-2c9d4629c578.xml&FT=Planning%20Application%20Search%20Results&XSLTemplate=/Northgate/PlanningExplorer/SiteFiles/Skins/Wandsworth/xslt/PL/PLResults.xslt&p=10';
options.uri = scroll_uri;
delete options.form;
delete options.followAllRedirects;
delete options.resolveWithFullResponse;
options.method = 'GET';
options.headers = {};
options.headers.Referer = Referer;
options.transform = function(body){
     return cheerio.load(body);
}

var $ = await rp(options);
```

Once I get the next page, I am given a table with 10 items and some pagination if there are more than 10 items available based on my POST request.

This all goes fine until I try to paginate to page 2. The resulting HTML body tells me that my search has expired and that I need to resubmit a search. That means going back to step 1 and submitting a POST request again, however that will always bring me to page 1 of the pagination.

Therefore, I need to somehow find a way to maintain a connection with this server while I 'scroll' through its pages.

I am using node.js & request-promise to make my requests.

The following is my code:

I have already tried maintaining cookies between requests.

Also, __VIEWSTATE shouldn't be the problem because the request to page 2 should be a GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround by using the headless browser "Puppeteer" in order to maintain a connection with the server. However, I still do not know how to solve this problem by making raw requests.